# Stuck on set theory question

Tags: elementary-set-theory

> Let $E$ be a set, let  $A_1,\ldots A_n$ be subsets of $E$.
>
> Let $A=\{A_1,\ldots,A_n\}$. Note that $A$ is included in the powerset of $E$.
>
> Let $\dot A $ be the smallest subset of $\cal{P}$$(E)$ stable under intersection, union and complement, and such that $A \subset \dot A$
>
> What can you say about $|\dot A|$ ?

I currently can't guess what the answer should be.

I think the stability conditions on $\dot A$ are very stringent, but I can't do anything with the "smallest" condition...

Comment: The only thing we can truly say is that $n\leq|\dot A|\leq 2^{|E|}$.

Comment: @AsafKaragila okay for the RHS, but how do you get the LHS ?

Comment: It is necessarily a subset of $\mathcal P(E)$.

Comment: @AsafKaragila We have the bound $2^{2^{2n}}$, methinks.

Comment: @Daniel: I'm not sure how tight that bound is. In any case it is the least between that bound and $2^{|E|}$, since we require this to be a subset of $\mathcal P(E)$.